# How to transform hapijs request payload boolean strings to boolean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I'm using hapi 17.2.2 with hapi-bodyparser 2.0.2 and experience the following behavior:

I have a form which sends the following data to my backend (hapi server) via JQuery ajax POST request.

```
{
  panel:{
    content:"asdf",
    visible: true
  }
}
```

However in the route handler, I get to see the following in the payload object:

```
payload: {
  'panel[about][visible]': 'true'
}
```

And after the body-parser plugin ran, I still see a boolean string instead of a boolean in the body object.

```
{
  panel:{ 
    about: { visible: 'true', content: 'asgasdgfa' }
  }
}
```

So for some reason the boolean value `true` get's transformed to the string `'true'` and never transformed back to the boolean value.

I feel like I'm missing some easy yet important part about payload processing because I'm not the first one running into this for sure.

It's not enough for me to just validate the value with Joi. To my understanding, Joi would only tell me if the value resembles a boolean value, but it would still be a string because Joi is only validating things but not actually transforming them. I haven't tried though and could be totally wrong with my assumption.

So is there a good way to tell hapi to actually preserve (or parse) boolean values if they occur in the payload?

Comment: Are you sure you are posting content type application/json and not form-data or form-urlencoded?

Comment: @Gangstead You're right, I'm sending form-urlencoded. So I was really missing something important. I haven't tried changing it yet, but I'll give an update here as soon as I know whether it's working with application/json or not.